# How to decode this string to utf-8 string?

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, decode

I have this code:

```
string URL = "http://translate.google.com/m?hl=vi&sl=en&tl=vi&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=song";
string s = "";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.4; U; Series60/5.0 Nokia5800d-1/21.0.025; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413");
s = client.DownloadString(URL);
```

When run I received a string with format as this string:

```
danh tÆ°Ì€ buá»•i há»p Ä‘á»ƒ ca hÃ¡t
```

to this string:

```
danh từ buổi họp để ca hát
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Where does the original come from? What is it encoded as?

Comment: Right. What encoding is the page in and why are you not setting the `client.Encoding` to that to begin with?

Comment: @Oded: Thank you, it worked, I'm newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting a `byte[]` that represents a string, you need to know what encoding was used before getting it.

In this case, it is UTF-8, so setting the `Encoding` of the `WebClient` to that results in the correct string:

```
string URL = "http://translate.google.com/m?hl=vi&sl=en&tl=vi&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=song";
string s = "";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.4; U; Series60/5.0 Nokia5800d-1/21.0.025; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413");
s = client.DownloadString(URL);
```